# How to store image data obtained from downloaded image file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to display image form a download image file,Not from direct image view url.

when i call this url =" http://api.example.com/api.php?a=profilepic&auth=tokenhere&file=filename "

it gives the download file.

By using $.get function can get data,But how can i convert to image format, so that i can store in a variable for further use.

if i use directly to image tag it works `<img src="http://api.example.com/api.php?
a=profilepic&auth=tokenhere&file=filename" >`  but i need store it Image object.

even tried using Image() object it didn't work.

even tried this http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#download didn't work.

can't change server side api call.

Need to change only in client side which use only js, jquery and html5 scripting

Need to know how get base64 data for the download image file

to make it look like this,

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgM...."/>
```

Looking forward for Your replay

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
var img = new Image(); 
img.onload = function () {
   // Code to execute when the image is completely downloaded.
}
img.src = "http://api.example.com/api.php? a=profilepic&auth=tokenhere&file=filename";
```

Comment: Is there any method to cache this image? Because I need to display this in some list (as user's profile image)

Comment: Store a reference to the <img> tag, you can dynamically build the <img> tags at the start of the application, keep references to them in an array and it will only download the content once.

Comment: how to store in a variable for further use without calling api again.

Comment: Have you considered trying a CSS sprite? This forces the image to download with the stylesheet, instead of tying it to a single element.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but i need to store for further use not using css to store it.Its like login user has single or multiple partner there profile pic need show in the list view depending on the category of event(task,valut,diary and so on). it may repeat same image.So that One's stored image, display for every Category event(task,vault..) list view and so on.